# Are there standards to compare naturalness of synthetic voices?

Tags: speech-synthesis

Say that I wanted to compare Siri and Google Voice in terms of naturalness or similarity to human speech. Obviously I could give a bunch of people a survey and collate their opinions — but I wonder if there is some industry standard used to objectively compare and contrast different voices in terms of how they sound, the ease with which they recognize fluid speech, and the quality of their chat functions.

Comment: Sounds like a binary classification problem.

Comment: Well, not just Siri vs google , but an objective way to compare all synthetic voices across criteria.

Comment: Are you looking for another Turing test?

Comment: No — this is about naturalness of voice quality — I am not interested in what is said